# Use range of addresses in column values to create new rows with single addresses in R

Tags: r, dataframe, range

Given the following data:

```
data <- data.frame("Street" = c("Example1", "Example2", "Example3", "Example4"),
                   "Number" = c("10-20a", "4b-8", NA, "14-16"))
```

```
    Street Number
1 Example1 10-20a
2 Example2   4b-8
3 Example3   <NA>
4 Example4  14-16
```

How can I create a data frame with each individual address that looks like this:

```
data_long <- data.frame("Street" = c(rep("Example1", 11), rep("Example2", 5),
                                     "Example3", rep("Example4", 3)),
                        "Number" = c(10:19,"20a", "4b", 5:8, NA, c(14:16)))
```

```
     Street Number
1  Example1     10
2  Example1     11
3  Example1     12
4  Example1     13
5  Example1     14
6  Example1     15
7  Example1     16
8  Example1     17
9  Example1     18
10 Example1     19
11 Example1    20a
12 Example2     4b
13 Example2      5
14 Example2      6
15 Example2      7
16 Example2      8
17 Example3   <NA>
18 Example4     14
19 Example4     15
20 Example4     16
```

I tried splitting the numbers and the letters and then using `rowwise` and`mutate` but it did not work because then the letter was next to each address.

Answer (score 2):

We `filter` the non-NA elements, extract one or more digits (\d+) with the letters ([a-z]) as 'v1' column in mutate, loop over the numbers extracted between the - using map2, get the sequence (:) as a list column, unnest (from tidyr) the list column to expand the data and replace the value in 'Number' based on the 'v1' column in `case_when` and bind with the `NA` rows

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
data %>% 
  filter(complete.cases(Number)) %>% 
  mutate(v1 = str_extract(Number, "\\d+[a-z]"),
  Number = map2(readr::parse_number(Number), 
   as.numeric(str_extract(Number, "-(\\d+)", group = 1)), `:`)) %>% 
  unnest(Number) %>% 
  mutate(Number = case_when(str_detect(v1, as.character(Number)) 
   ~ v1, 
  TRUE ~ as.character(Number)), v1 = NULL) %>% 
  bind_rows(data %>%
    filter(is.na(Number))) %>% 
    arrange(Street)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 × 2
   Street   Number
   <chr>    <chr> 
 1 Example1 10    
 2 Example1 11    
 3 Example1 12    
 4 Example1 13    
 5 Example1 14    
 6 Example1 15    
 7 Example1 16    
 8 Example1 17    
 9 Example1 18    
10 Example1 19    
11 Example1 20a   
12 Example2 4b    
13 Example2 5     
14 Example2 6     
15 Example2 7     
16 Example2 8     
17 Example3 <NA>  
18 Example4 14    
19 Example4 15    
20 Example4 16
```

Comment: I get an error because of the NA: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `Number = map2(...)`.
Caused by error in `map2()`:
ℹ In index: 3.
Caused by error in `.x:.y`:
! NA/NaN argument
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that was generated with the help of @akrun (here: [How to expand rows and fill in the numbers between given start and end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75164021/how-to-expand-rows-and-fill-in-the-numbers-between-given-start-and-end/75164032#75164032)):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(readr)

data %>% 
  separate_rows(Number, sep = "-") %>% 
  group_by(Street) %>% 
  mutate(Number1 = ifelse(is.na(Number), 0, parse_number(Number))) %>% 
  tidyr::complete(Number1 = full_seq(Number1, period = 1)) %>% 
  mutate(Number = coalesce(Number, as.character(Number1)), .keep="unused")
```

```
   Street   Number
   <chr>    <chr> 
 1 Example1 10    
 2 Example1 11    
 3 Example1 12    
 4 Example1 13    
 5 Example1 14    
 6 Example1 15    
 7 Example1 16    
 8 Example1 17    
 9 Example1 18    
10 Example1 19    
11 Example1 20a   
12 Example2 4b    
13 Example2 5     
14 Example2 6     
15 Example2 7     
16 Example2 8     
17 Example3 0     
18 Example4 14    
19 Example4 15    
20 Example4 16
```