# How to expand rows and fill in the numbers between given start and end

Tags: r, dplyr, fill, expand

I have this data frame:

```
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 10))

      x
  <dbl>
1     1
2    10
```

I want this:

```
      x
   <int>
 1     1
 2     2
 3     3
 4     4
 5     5
 6     6
 7     7
 8     8
 9     9
10    10
```

Unfortunately I can't remember how I have to approach. I tried `expand.grid`, `uncount`, `runner::fill_run`.

**Update:** The real world data ist like this with groups and given start and end number. Here are only two groups:

```
  df <- tibble(group = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), 
               x = c(10,30, 1, 10)) 

  group     x
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A        10
2 A        30
3 B         1
4 B        10
```

Comment: Provide more realistic data, otherwise the answer is simply `1:10`

Comment: Ok thanks I will add a data frame.

Comment: If you want to KISS it: `df <- tibble(x = 1:10)` or `df <- tibble(x = seq(1, 10, 1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need `full_seq` with either `summarise` or `reframe` or `tidyr::complete`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>%
   reframe(x = full_seq(x, period = 1))
   # or with 
   #tidyr::complete(x = full_seq(x, period = 1))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 31 × 2
   group     x
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 A        10
 2 A        11
 3 A        12
 4 A        13
 5 A        14
 6 A        15
 7 A        16
 8 A        17
 9 A        18
10 A        19
# … with 21 more rows
```

Comment: Ah, ok it was `complete` that I tried but without `full_seq`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TarJae with `uncount`, you can still do i.t. `tibble(x = 10) %>% uncount(x, .id = 'x')`

Comment: Both work perfect. But why `.id = 'x'`?

Comment: @TarJae I removed the option as it wouldn't work when the start is different than 1

Answer (score 1):

A simple base R variation:

```
group <- c(rep("A", 21), rep("B ", 10))
x <- c(10:30, 1:10)
df <- tibble(group, x)
df
# A tibble: 31 × 2
   group     x
   <chr> <int>
 1 A        10
 2 A        11
 3 A        12
 4 A        13
 5 A        14
 6 A        15
```

And here's an `expand.grid` solution:

```
g1 <- expand.grid(group = "A", x = 20:30)
g2 <- expand.grid(group = "B", x = 1:10)
df <- rbind(g1, g2)
df
   group  x
1      A 20
2      A 21
3      A 22
4      A 23
5      A 24
6      A 25
7      A 26
```

Comment: There is no need for expand.grid here.  `data.frame(group = "A", x = 20:30)` would give the same result. Also, will not scale well, imagine 100 groups.

Answer (score 1):

Using *base*:

```
stack(sapply(split(df$x, df$group), function(i) seq(i[ 1 ], i[ 2 ])))
```